# Directory Seacher issue, how to get primary SMTP only?

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, smtp

I have the below snippet from my authentication login page

How can I modify it so that it takes the Primary SMTP mail address from AD?  Currently it appears that it takes the first one that it finds.

Is there a property to only get the primary mail address?

```
adsSearcher.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + strAccountId + ")";
        adsSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");

        try
        {
            SearchResult adsSearchResult = adsSearcher.FindOne();

            bool bSucceeded = true;

            string strAuthenticatedBy = "Active Directory";
            string strError = "User has been authenticated by Active Directory.";
            adsEntry.Close();
            try
            {
                if (adsSearchResult.Properties["mail"] != null && adsSearchResult.Properties["mail"].Count > 0)
                {


                        Session["email"] = adsSearchResult.Properties["mail"][0].ToString().ToLower();


                }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here as the `mail` attribute is NOT a multi-valued attribute and always contains the user's primary smtp address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is actually to retrieve the `proxyAddresses` attribute. Each entry in that attribute is prefixed with a protocol (e.g. SIP:, SMTP:, etc.). The proxy with the capitalized prefix (e.g. SMTP: vs smtp:) is the primary address for that protocol. The `mail` attribute /should/ be in sync but it's not always the case.

Comment: Great, I will try that.  For some reason I have some users where it takes the secondary SMTP address instead of the primary.